# Server certificate verification failed when updating

Tags: package-management, updates, certificates

I am experiencing an issue when updating packages. I get the following error message:

```
server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

If I manually enter the package link:

https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/stable/binary-amd64/Packages

into the web browser, I get the red HTTPS not secure message with the `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` message. However, if I enter the package link in the web browser of another computer, it loads with no problems.

What I have tried to fix it:

- Checking that my time is correct and synchronized using NTP
- Updating the root certificates using:

  update-ca-certificates

  update-ca-certificates --fresh
- Reinstalling root certificates using:

  apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates

However, this did not fix the problem.
Is there anything else I can do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was not with the certificates. The default gateway of the Ubuntu box is running a transparent proxy and after adding the Ubuntu box to the addresses that bypass the proxy, this fixed the problem.